# Настройка модулей в pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pip

Всё началось с того, что я скачал python kivy. И вышло так что PyCharm не видел эту библиотеку, так как я установил её через pip, а не через местный установщик. В попытках решить эту проблему, я решил изменить путь в project interpreter.И вроде всё заработало, и я решил параллельно использовать ещё одну библиотеку в своём проекте. Эту библиотеку я установил через установщик от PyCharm. И в итоге это библиотека не видна. Я решил установить её так же, через pip. Но командная строка мне выдала ошибку

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pymorhy (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for pymorhy

И что мне с этим делать?

Answer (score 2):

Вы, вероятно, неверно указали имя устанавливаемого модуля в `pip` (пропустили p перед h слове morphy). Попробуйте `pip install pymorphy2` (как советует PyPi). Или просто `pip install pymorphy`, но в этом я не уверен.

Comment: `pymorphy is deprecated if favor of https://github.com/kmike/pymorphy2` https://pypi.org/project/pymorphy/

Comment: @insolor Добавьте каких-то пояснений

Comment: pymorphy уже не поддерживается (судя по последнему коммиту на гитхабе - с 2012 года ориентировочно). Нужно использовать pymorphy2.

Comment: @insolor Потому я и рекомендовал этот вариант в первую очередь. Второй добавил на случай, если для автора принципиально использование именно первой версии

Answer (score 0):

Если вы создавали проект через *PyCharm* с виртуальной средой, то автоматически в папке с проектом он создаст папку этой среды (`venv`). Установка туда пакетов осуществляется через вкладку '*Python Packages*' на нижней панели инструментов (скриншот ниже).

[image: Вкладка, через которую нужно устанавливать пакеты в vevn в PyCharm.]

К сожалению, в *PyCharm* нельзя создать проект без установки туда какой либо среды (venv, poetry, pipenv или же Conda). Но, вы можете создать папку на вашем компьютере и уже открыть ее в PyCharm. Уже там *PyCharm* будет использовать ту версию Python которая у вас установлена (лично у меня стоит 3.10.2). Если вы хотите сменить версию используемого интерпретатора Python, то в нижнем правом углу есть вкладка выбора интерпретатора (обычно на ней написано 'Python' и правее версия используемого интерпретатора, на скриншоте ниже показано).

[image: Там где написано 'Python 3.10' это и есть вкладка с интерпретаторами.]

После того как вы нажали на эту вкладку вам выпадет небольшое окошко которое должно будет выглядеть так:

[image: Вид окна для выбора интерпретатора проекта.]

Здесь вы можете выбрать другую версию интерпретатора, настроить их или же добавить новый. Если вы создавали проект через PyCharm c виртуальной средой (virtualenv) то у вас оно будет выглядеть так:

[image: Окно выбора интерпретатора в проекте с виртуальной средой.]

Выше вы можете заметить еще один интерпретатор добавленный самим PyCharm при создании проекта.

Так к чему я веду? Вам нужно смотреть на то какой интерпретатор использует PyCharm, потому что именно через него он будет запускать ваш скрипт. В PyCharm есть простой способ как просмотреть установленные пакеты в выбранной версии интерпретатора Python. Для этого можем воспользоваться вкладкой в нижнем правом углу (о ней уже шла речь) далее 'Interpreter Settings...'. Или же самому через настройки, по пути Settings >> Project: {название вашего проекта} >> Python Interpreter. Сама вкладка будет выглядеть так:

[image: Список пакетов в текущем интерпретаторе.]

В списке 'Python Interpreter' вы можете выбрать версию интерпретатора которую будет использовать PyCharm в текущем проекте. Там же, вы можете добавить другой интерпретатор (если он у вас установлен на компьютере) нажав в выпадающем списке 'Show All...' и далее в открывшемся окне на плюс в верхнем левом углу. Если же вы используете виртуальную среду, то во вкладке 'Python Packages' уже будет показан список пакетов которой установлен в текущем проекте.